# Isomorphic spaces and bases

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vector-space-isomorphism

I know P2 and R3 are isomorphic since dim(P2) = dim(R3) = 3. Does this mean that if B is a basis for R3, it is also a basis for P2? Is there a theorem that states this?

I'm coming from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GdXCBG3dRTo, at 2:00 in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. No theorem can possibly say that, since $\mathbb R^3\cap P_2=\emptyset$. In particular, no non-empty subset of $\mathbb R^3$ can possibly also be a subset of $P_2$.

Asserting that $\mathbb R^3$ and $P_2$ are isomorphic simply means that there is a linear isomorphism from $\mathbb R^3$ onto $P_2$.

Comment: Which notwithstanding maps any basis of $\mathbf R^3$ onto a basis of $P_2$.

Comment: I edited my post with where I got the question - she says in the video that since dim(P2) = 3, 3 linearly independent vectors must be a basis for P2. Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: Well… yes. Any $3$ linearly independent vectors from a $3$-dimensional vector space form a basis of that space. What has that to do with your question?

Comment: If B is a basis for R3, doesn't B have to be made up of 3 linearly independent vectors? So B would also be a basis for P2?

Comment: they are not the same space, aren't they? why would those 3 vectors even exist in the other space? It's the image of the 3 linear independent vectors who form a basis in the codomain-space.

Comment: Ah, I see my issue. Thanks for the clarification